# Is !foo = expression legal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, warnings

**Note: I am not exactly sure what to name the question, so if someone has a better idea please edit it.**

I will jump right into the question, since there isn't any fore-explaining required.

This code:

```
!foo = true
```

generates this warning

```
warning: found = in conditional, should be ==
```

I would understand if this was happening after an `if` or `unless` statement, but this couldn't be further away from them (exaggerating). I do realise I could use:

```
foo = true
!foo
```

I suppose, the warning isn't a big deal, but it is a bit irritating that Ruby is assuming I am doing something wrong—when I am not.

---

Questions:

- Is this a bug?
- Can the warning be disabled?

Thanks!

Comment: i'm curious and cannot test it now, but `!(foo = true)` should work?

Comment: I tried that already, but it generated the same warning. D:

Comment: @withadot. Simple solution: avoid all assignments in conditional expressions ;-) [I violate this rule on *rare* occasions, but...]

Comment: ruby warns about a lot of things which are perfectly legal.. btw if it's really just `foo`, a local, then what's the point of assignment?

Comment: Oh, it was an instance variable. Did I say local? Sorry, I failed if I said local. I didn't write `@foo` because `foo` looks a bit nicer. *blushes*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### *Is* legal. *Not* a bug. The warning *can* be suppressed.

You can disable the warning with:

```
$VERBOSE = nil
```

It's interesting, `$VERBOSE` is a case where setting something to `false` does something different than setting it to `nil`.

By the way, the other answers, at least initially, tend to assume that Ruby parses the expression as

```
(!foo) = true
```

... but that's not the case. It is parsed as:

```
!(foo = true)
```

... and so it's doing exactly what the OP wanted. And there is no specification or ratified standard for Ruby, so if it works in MRI (the reference implementation) then it's legal.

Comment: +1 for the way it's parsed (It got me too! :-/). That would explain why it's *not* an outright Syntax Error, but just a warning on an assignment in a conditional.

Answer (score 4):

As previous answers already suggested, that's not a valid thing of doing what you want to do.

```
!foo = true
```

evaluates as

```
!(foo = true)
```

That is, assign `true` to `foo` and get the negation of the result of that assignment, which boils down to

```
!true
```

or

```
false
```

If you want to store `!true`, it has to be

```
foo = !true
```

If you want to assign true to foo and the negation to another variable, it'd be

```
foo2 = !(foo = true)
```

and that will still cause a warning, because after all it is an assignment in a conditional.

> I actually want to assign true to foo, and then get the opposite of foo on the stack

Doesn't really make much sense. You "get something on the stack" by assigning it to a variable, like `foo2` in my example.

If the purpose here is to assign to an instance variable and return the negation from a method, then yes, you will have to first assign to the variable and then explicitly return the negation. This is not a bug in Ruby but actually a feature, and for the sake of clean code, you shouldn't be doing it in one line because it's basically indistinguishable from the common bug of using `=` when `==` was meant.

Comment: Well, it is actually at the end ov a method, and I thought it would be random if it returned `false` (I know I used `true` in the example), so I thought I could simply fix it by adding a single byte of code. I just settled for returning `nil` instead. Thanks. It was a brilliant answer, too! ♥

Comment: A method either has a well-defined, purposeful return value or, at the discretion of the programmer, a "random" value or if you're concerned about leaking objects, nil. So yeah, either way is a better idea than forcefully returning true ;)

Comment: @DigitalRoss He is actually a she. :¬(

Comment: @dominikh, the OP seemed to understand exactly how the expression was parsed, and it's what she *was* trying to do. The general questions were whether this was allowed, if there was a bug, and the specific question was: *can the warning be suppressed?*

Comment: Well, good thing then you described how to hide the warnings, instead of how to do it properly :)

Comment: Here's another use case—not much use except maybe in tests, but valid: `def nil_once_then_always_true; @called_already || !(@called_already = true); end`

Answer (score 4):

It's only a warning, and is evaluating as you expect.  You can disable warnings temporarily by assigning $VERBOSE=nil.

```
save_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, nil
result = !foo = true
$VERBOSE = save_verbos
result
```

Other [places on the net](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/06/ruby-verbose-mode/), suggest making a helper method ala

```
module Kernel
  def silence_warnings
    with_warnings(nil) { yield }
  end

  def with_warnings(flag)
    old_verbose, $VERBOSE = $VERBOSE, flag
    yield
  ensure
    $VERBOSE = old_verbose
  end
end unless Kernel.respond_to? :silence_warnings
```

But, I just tried this in 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 and it was ineffective at suppressing the "warning: found = in conditional, should be =="

Comment: LOL! That's a creative solution. I decided to return `nil`, since it's the responsible thing to do.~ ;¬)

Answer (score 1):

That's technically an invalid left hand assignment. You want

foo = !true

You can't assign a value to the opposite of the object. What is not foo? =)

Comment: I actually want to assign `true` to `foo`, and then get the opposite of `foo` on the stack.

Comment: well if you want to get the opposite than you say whatImGetting = !foo;

Comment: That wouldn't be a one-liner, then. :(

Comment: This isn't really a correct statement, although it's a totally understandable analysis, and would be correct for most languages other than Ruby. But as it happens, Ruby parses the OP's statement as `!(foo = true)`

Comment: as pointed out, it's not an invalid lvalue, the warning is just a lint message.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake in your code:

```
!var = anything
```

Is wrong.  You're trying to assign to either `TrueClass` or `FalseClass`, which is (probably) what `!var` returns.

You want:

```
!var == true
```

Now you're doing the comparison (albeit an unnecessary one).

Comment: I don't need a comparison, though. I need to assign `true` to `foo` and then return the opposite of what was assigned... And I want it to be a one-liner.

Comment: This is what I thought at first, also, but I tested it (and looked at the yacc grammar) and it turns out that Ruby parses the statement as `!(foo = true)`